# Refer to Theorem A,B,C,

Tags: cross-referencing

I usually number theorems and lemmas and so in my papers as Theorem 1.1, Lemma 1.2, Theorem 2.1,... but sometimes, in the introduction section, I want the main theorems appeared as Theorem A, Theorem B, ... To achieve that, I use

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{latexsym,enumerate,amssymb, xcolor,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\newtheorem*{thmA}{Theorem A}

\newtheorem*{thmB}{Theorem B}

\begin{thmA}\label{thm:mainA}
This is a nice theorem.
\end{thmA}

\end{document}
```

However, when I refer to Theorem A using `\ref{thm:mainA}`, it appears in the resulting pdf file as Theorem 1, instead of Theorem A.

My questions are: is that the standard way to produce Theorem A,B,..., and how do we properly refer to them?

Answer (score 6):

You'll be luckier if you do

```
\newtheorem{mainthm}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\themainthm}{\Alph{mainthm}}
```

then calling simply

```
\begin{mainthm}\label{thm:mainA}
This is the first main theorem.
\end{mainthm}
```

and similarly for theorem B and theorem C.

You don't want to load `latexsym`, but rather `amssymb`. You should also consider `enumitem` instead of `enumerate`.

Full code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{enumerate,amssymb, xcolor,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{mainthm}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\themainthm}{\Alph{mainthm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mainthm}\label{thm:mainA}
This is a nice theorem.
\end{mainthm}

\begin{mainthm}\label{thm:mainB}
This is another nice theorem.
\end{mainthm}

\begin{mainthm}\label{thm:mainC}
This is a very nice theorem.
\end{mainthm}

Theorem~\ref{thm:mainA} is nice. Also~\ref{thm:mainB} is,
but Theorem~\ref{thm:mainC} is nicer.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!